# How to join 3 tables with different primary key

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables (`useraccount`, `category` and `complaint`). `username`, `categoryID` and `referenceNum` are the primary key in each table respectively.

In table `complaint`, I have `categoryID` (from table `category`) and `username` (from table `useraccount`) as foreign keys. But `referenceNum` is not a foreign key in both `category` and `useraccount` table. I need to retrieve the `fullName` from `useraccount` and `categoryName` from `category`.

How can I join them using `categoryID` and `username`?

My current SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM complaint 
JOIN category AND useraccount USING (categoryID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using standard SQL JOINs:

```
SELECT * 
FROM complaint c
INNER JOIN category ca ON c.categoryId = ca.categoryId
INNER JOIN useraccount u ON c.username = u.username
```

Depending on what your **concrete RDBMS** is (you didn't specify in your question), you might be able to simplify that query a bit - but this is standard SQL and should work with just about any system.